# Split python dictionary to result in all combinations of values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':{'d':[4,5], 'e':[6,7]}}
```

I need to derive all the combinations out of it as below.

```
{'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':{'d':4, 'e':6}}
{'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':{'d':4, 'e':7}}
{'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':{'d':5, 'e':6}}
{'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':{'d':5, 'e':7}}
{'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':{'d':4, 'e':6}}
```

and so on. There could be any level of nesting here
Please let me know how to achieve this
Something that I tried is pasted below but definitely was reaching nowhere

```
def gen_combinations(data):
    my_list =[]
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                gen_combinations(v)
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for i in range(len(v)):
                    temp_dict = data.copy()
                    temp_dict[k] = v[i]
                    print temp_dict

my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':{'d':[4,5], 'e':[6,7]}}

gen_combinations(my_dict)
```

Which resulted in

```
{'a': 1, 'c': {'e': [6, 7], 'd': [4, 5]}, 'b': [3]}
{'a': 2, 'c': {'e': [6, 7], 'd': [4, 5]}, 'b': [3]}
{'e': 6, 'd': [4, 5]}
{'e': 7, 'd': [4, 5]}
{'e': [6, 7], 'd': 4}
{'e': [6, 7], 'd': 5}
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': {'e': [6, 7], 'd': [4, 5]}, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Please, let us know what you have tried so far !

Comment: I presume you want to flatten the nested dicts also?

Comment: @Suren can you look at discussion under my answer? What output for key `e` do you want for `{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': {'d': {4: [3, 4]}, 'e': [6, 7, [1, 2]]}}`?

Comment: @germn , I will have only nested dicts but the list will be single . It will never be [6,7,[1,2]] but always of tyep [6,7,1,2]. So your code will work great for me.Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Suren, you're welcome. I updated answer to make code less complex.

Comment: @germn , Can you please let me know how to modified this to handle list of dicts. I mean if my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'e':[7], 'f':{'x':[{'a':[3,5]},{'a':[4]}] } }. I want the output like :  {'a':1, 'e':7, 'f':{'x':[{'a':[3]},{'a':[4]}] } }. Bit struggling with this.

Comment: @Suren, I edited answer, second code snippet will handle list of dicts as specific case. It's hard to make solution universal since it's unclear how script should work. For example, what output should be for `{'x': [1, {'a': [2,3]}, {'a': [4]}]}`?

Comment: @germn Again thanks a ton!! was really struggling..This works like a charm!

Comment: @germn , Can you please take a look at a similar question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227574/how-to-split-a-python-dictionary-for-its-values-on-matching-a-key

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from itertools import product


my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':{'d':[4,5], 'e':[6,7]}}


def process(d):
    to_product = []  # [[('a', 1), ('a', 2)], [('b', 3),], ...]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            to_product.append([(k, i) for i in v])
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            to_product.append([(k, i) for i in process(v)])
        else:
            to_product.append([(k, v)])
    return [dict(l) for l in product(*to_product)]

for i in process(my_dict):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 6, 'd': 4}}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 6, 'd': 4}}
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 6, 'd': 5}}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 6, 'd': 5}}
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 7, 'd': 4}}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 7, 'd': 4}}
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 7, 'd': 5}}
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': {'e': 7, 'd': 5}}
```

**Upd:**

Code that works as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198540/split-python-dictionary-to-result-in-all-combinations-of-values?noredirect=1#comment60043432_36198540):

```
from itertools import product


my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'e':[7], 'f':{'x':[{'a':[3,5]}, {'a':[4]}] } }

def process(d):
    to_product = []  # [[('a', 1), ('a', 2)], [('b', 3),], ...]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list) and all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in v):
            # specific case, when list of dicts process differently...
            c = product(*list(process(i) for i in v))
            to_product.append([(k, list(l)) for l in c])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            to_product.append([(k, i) for i in v])
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            to_product.append([(k, i) for i in process(v)])
        else:
            to_product.append([(k, v)])
    return [dict(l) for l in product(*to_product)]

for i in process(my_dict):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{'f': {'x': [{'a': 3}, {'a': 4}]}, 'a': 1, 'e': 7}
{'f': {'x': [{'a': 3}, {'a': 4}]}, 'a': 2, 'e': 7}
{'f': {'x': [{'a': 5}, {'a': 4}]}, 'a': 1, 'e': 7}
{'f': {'x': [{'a': 5}, {'a': 4}]}, 'a': 2, 'e': 7}
```

Comment: Great answer, didn't know about `product` function before, very helpful!

Comment: Nice! How about allowing any other iterable except just filtering for list? In the lines of `try: to_product.append([{k: i} for i in v]) except TypeError: ...`?

Comment: I think this will fail for nested dicts  `{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': {'d': {4: [3, 4]}, 'e': [6, 7, [1, 2]]}}`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham looks like it works. Output is http://pastebin.com/1qrWs6tv , right?

Comment: I think  `'e': [1, 2]` should be flattened presuming the want all nesting, I think a bigger problem may be using recursion for combinations, won't take a very great deal of elements to blow the stack.

Comment: @hochl, well, it can be added, but I think code is already complex.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, may be. It depends on how task exactly sounds. Based on question and example, `'e': [1, 2]` doesn't seem to be mistake to me.

Comment: The OP mentioned *There could be any level of nesting here* so based on that I imagine all e:1... , e:2 ... are valid outputs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham based on example, I think he meant nested dicts. But ok, let's wait what OP will say.

Comment: Yes, I meant only nested dicts, not nested list. Thanks everyone for the quick help!!

Comment: Nice work! But I'd probably write it as a generator. Eg, replace the `return` line with `for L in product(*to_product):` `yield dict(L)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring the only side effect there is that any validation in the generator is postponed until the first value is requested.  This will sometimes break code written using EAFP principles.

Comment: Ah, good point, @RoadieRich. But I guess that _shouldn't_ be a problem **if** the input `dict` is well-formed. I was just thinking about saving RAM, since the returned list could easily get _very_ large.

Comment: @PM2Ring you could also get the same effect, *and* perform any validation at call time (I think...), just by turning the list comp into a gen ex (replacing the square brackets with parentheses).

Comment: @RoadieRich: I don't think that would make a difference from my suggestion (but I could be totally wrong :) ).

Comment: @PM2Ring I checked. The "preamble" is evaluated at call time, the genex is returned, but none of the products are computed until requested, meaning no huge lists sitting around.  The wonders of `itertools.product`.

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail: You may like to take a look at Suren's "follow-on" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227574/how-to-split-a-python-dictionary-for-its-values-on-matching-a-key

Answer (score -1):

Solve it with two steps.

First replace each dict with a list of dicts generated by gen_combinations, called recursively.

Second, make the inner join between all keys. Each key has a flat list now.